# Wordpress REST api last page

Tags: wordpress, rest

I have an API call from Vue, that makes paginating of Wordpress posts, the number of pages and offset work perfectly, I can make first page, previous and next page queries work perfectly with the offset parameter

```
https://example-page.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=5&per_page=12&offset=12
```

But, for the last page I don't know what should be the offset, if the number of posts change. How can I find out this number, which is the last page in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the total number of pages from the [`X-WP-Total`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters) response header.

From that you can compute an offset for the last page.

```
const itemsPerPage = 12;
const xWPTotal = /* value from response header */
const offset = itemsPerPage * Math.round(xWPTotal / itemsPerPage - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, just for future reference, this is how it is done `.then(res => parseInt(res.headers.get('x-wp-total')))`

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in the header response with this code:

```
X-WP-Total: total items
X-WP-TotalPages: total pages/last page number
```